# Moment.js converting the date incorrectly in case of future dates

Tags: javascript, json, momentjs

I am using moment.js to compare two dates in my javascript code. 
The input values are passed from a JSON string.

When I provide date 21/01/2050 00:00 (MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm FORMAT), the resulting date shows as 21/1/1950 00:00. 
I tried using the below options:

1. `moment(item["End Date"]).utc().format()`
2. `moment(item["Start Date"]).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm')`
3. `moment(new Date(item["Start Date"])).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm')`

But these are still giving me year as 1950 instead of 2050.

Is there a way to format this one correctly?

Comment: [I get 2050, not 1950.](https://jsfiddle.net/krythpbL/1/)...  (Had to correct the input from DD/MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY, though; could be a locale issue.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your input is not in ISO 8601 or RFC 2822 format recognized by [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, we then check if the string matches the [RFC 2822 Date time](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) format before dropping to the fall back of `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found.

**Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings is inconsistent. Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.

> 

For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

So you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), passing `'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'` as second argument.

Here a live sample:

```js
var input = "21/01/2050 00:00";
console.log( moment(input, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```